# Does the UK text and data mining exception to copyright allow non-commercial projects free use of anything on the internet to train their models?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, fair-use, artificial-intelligence

On the UK government page on Exceptions to copyright the text and data mining exception is described as:

> Text and data mining is the use of automated analytical techniques to analyse text and data for patterns, trends and other useful information. Text and data mining usually requires copying of the work to be analysed.
>
> An exception to copyright exists which allows researchers to make copies of any copyright material for the purpose of computational analysis if they already have the right to read the work (that is, they have ‘lawful access’ to the work). This exception only permits the making of copies for the purpose of text and data mining for non-commercial research. Researchers will still have to buy subscriptions to access material; this could be from many sources including academic publishers.
>
> Publishers and content providers will be able to apply reasonable measures to maintain their network security or stability but these measures should not prevent or unreasonably restrict researcher’s ability to text and data mine. Contract terms that stop researchers making copies to carry out text and data mining will be unenforceable.

I interpret this as you are free to "apply automated analytical techniques to analyse text and data for patterns, trends and other useful information" content that would be otherwise protected.  That sounds like a precise description of training a large language model/chatbot on the text of a web site or a latent diffusion/text-to-image model on the images.

You are required to be non-commercial so OpenAI would not be covered by this exception but as I understand it most for the open source models on [hugging face](https://huggingface.co/) would be.  It is also required that you have ‘lawful access’ to the content, but that would include anything freely available on the internet (though again not [OpenAI using LibGen](https://www.theregister.com/2023/09/12/openai_copyright_lawsuits/)).

Is this a correct interpretation?  Would a non-commercial hobby AI developer be free to use any content that they are allowed to access on the internet to train their models even if such use if found to be infringing in the [multiple](https://www.reuters.com/legal/transactional/lawsuits-accuse-ai-content-creators-misusing-copyrighted-work-2023-01-17/) [law suits](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-66231268) against commercial companies about [this issue](https://techcrunch.com/2023/01/27/the-current-legal-cases-against-generative-ai-are-just-the-beginning/?guccounter=1)?